# I have a contract class with a proerty that is changed

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have the follwing class in a common library:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class WcfFileStream
    {
        private string _name;
        [DataMember]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _namee; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        private System.IO.Stream _file;
        //[MessageBodyMember]
        [DataMember]
        public System.IO.Stream File
        {
            get { return _file; }
            set { _file = value; }
        }
```

I have the property Name, that is System.IO.Stream, but when I create a new WcfFileStream in my client to be send to the service, the type is System.IO.MemoryStream. Why?

This throw an exception, System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, because it is expected an Stream, not a MemoryStream.

Why if my property is a Stream, when I create the object is a memoryStream?

Thanks.

Comment: `Stream` is an abstract class which you can't instantiate. What code do you use to create a new `WcfFileStream` object?

Comment: thanks, I did not realize it.